# How to fix a Surface 2RT touch screen which doesn't respond

Tags: windows-rt, surface-2

I've been pulled into diagnosing a problem on a Surface 2RT. The touch screen has stopped responding. However, the Windows key on the tablet below the screen does respond.

As recommended from sites I've seen, we

- cleaned the screen with a microfiber cloth
- did a refresh in the system
- and uninstalled the touch screen driver

Now the touchscreen entry is missing.  I was hoping that scanning for hardware changes would help. It didn't. I was hoping a restart would help. It didn't. This thing still functions with the attached keyboard and a mouse.

**Update**
The screen is still unresponsive after a complete reset.

Comment: Have you done a complete system reset as per https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-gb/support/hardware-and-drivers/troubleshoot-the-surface-touchscreen?os=windows-10 ?

Comment: Completely reset. No luck.

Comment: If you've got a USB keyboard/mouse plugged in to the Surface click "Start" then start typing "Calibrate the screen for pen or touch input". This should bring up a window allowing you to see the tablet settings and do further reset/calibrate...?

Comment: So complete system reset and tried the calibrate function with no luck. The start button on the tablet functions (with haptic vibration). However, no touch with in the illuminated section of the screen does.

Answer (score -1):

I have had some luck updating through windows update, it appears to be a firmware issue, sometimes it fixes it and some times it fail. its been about 50/50 for.